# how to validate list in web api

Tags: list, validation, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a web api which accepts list of customers in from file upload. Each row in file represents single customers. There can be 'n' customers in a single file.

For each row, validation check is required. The error messages needs to be displayed in respective row.

POST /api/customers List if this is the API, how to perform validations?​

Code is something like this,

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadCustomers(List<Customer> customers)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

            //Some action
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a property to your Customer object such as "IsValid," then as you iterate through each row, validate and set the value to true or false.

```
public class Customer {
   //...
   public bool IsValid { get; set; } = false
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadCustomers(List<Customer> customers)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

            foreach(var cust in customers)
           {
               if (IsValid(cust))
                { cust.IsValid = true; }
           }

           return customers;
        }

public bool IsValid(Customer cust)
{
  // Validation logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am yet to write code for it. Some sample code is edited in post. Since, I am new to web api, finding it difficult to phrase the problem.

Comment: I think this statement is not required,  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(); as it will validate domain level validationattribute.

Comment: I included the code provided in the question, but I agree it may not be required.

Comment: How can I extend above code to display errors with respective fields?

Comment: That is probably worth asking in a separate question.